# How to get scalar to align two array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

For a given two equal length array, A and B. The length of A and B are larger than 1. Both arrays are floating point numbers and they could be negative and positive.

How to get a scalar, a, to get minimum MSE(A, aB).

MSE is mean squared error.

a = argmin((sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(A_i-aB_i)^2)/N) where N is the length of array.

Obviously, we can run exhaustive search to find optimized a.

Is there any better algorithm to find a?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (also prove it indeed minimizes):

[image]

This will give you an `O(N)` solution, you have to just compute 2 summations to get the optimal `a`.

Comment: Thanks. Should denominator be B_i^2?